# Using List<interface> within another Interface C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, interface

I'm trying to create an interface for a model class in ASP.NET MVC2 and I wonder if I can use a `List<interface>` within another interface. It's better if I give a code example.

I have two interfaces, a terminal can have multiple bays. So I code my interfaces like the following.

Bay Interface:

```
public interface IBay
{
    // Properties
    int id {get; set;}
    string name {get;set;}
    // ... other properties
}
```

Terminal Interface:

```
public interface ITerminal
{
    // Properties
    int id {get;set;}
    string name {get;set;}
    // ... other properties
    List<IBay> bays {get;set;}
}
```

My question is when I implement my class based on these interfaces how to I set up the list of bays. Am I going to have to do the list of bays outside the ITerminal interface and inside the concrete implementation?

My goal is to be able to do the following:

Concrete implementation:
Bay Class:

```
class Bay : IBay
{
    // Constructor
    public Bay()
    {
        // ... constructor
    }
}
```

Terminal Class:

```
class Terminal : ITerminal
{
    // Constructor
    public Terminal()
    {
        // ... constructor
    }
}
```

And then be able to access the list of bays like this

```
Terminal.Bays
```

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code looks fine, other than the general design suggestion that Bays should be `IList<IBay>`.  Is something about it not working?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand sorry. The ITerminal interface means you need to add the `Bays` accessor to your Terminal object, and then you can create a `List<IBay>` and add `Bay` objects to it and then return that from the accessor. Or do you mean how to set it up so that you can return a `List<Bay>` as a `List<IBay>`?

Comment: @ChrisShain: This was more of a structure question and best practices.

Comment: @Rup: I will use IList<IBay> instead of what I used in the sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work fine.  Just realize that your Terminal class will still contain a `List<IBay>`, which can be populated with `Bay` instances as needed.  (Note that I would recommend using `IList<IBay>` instead, however.)

If you want terminal to return a concrete `Bay` types, then you would need to redesign your Terminal interface, and modify this as:

```
public interface ITerminal<T> where T : IBay
{
    // Properties
    int Id {get;set;}
    string Name {get;set;}
    IList<T> Bays {get;}
}

public Terminal : ITerminal<Bay>
{
     private List<Bay> bays = new List<Bay>();
     IList<Bay> Bays { get { return bays; } }
     // ...
     public Terminal()
     {
         bays.Add(new Bay { //...
```

However, there may be little value in adding this complexity.

Comment: +1: I would personally prefer this approach (generics), provided that terminals will always have homogeneous lists of bays (i.e. of the same type or sharing a common base type).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take some of your answer and combine it with @Douglas described above.

Comment: @Douglas: Yes the Bays will always have same type so I will implement this interface like this.

Answer (score 6):

You can initialize a list-of-interface by populating it with concrete instances. For example, to initialize your `Terminal` class using [object and collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), you could use code similar to:

```
Terminal terminal = new Terminal
{
    id = 0,
    name = "My terminal",
    bays = new List<IBay>
    {
        new Bay { id = 1, name = "First bay" },
        new Bay { id = 2, name = "Second bay" },
        new Bay { id = 3, name = "Third bay" },
    }
};
```

Some points about your code:

- By convention, all public properties should be PascalCased. Use `Id` or `ID` instead of `id`; `Name` instead of `name`; `Bays` instead of `bays`.
- Since you’re putting so much emphasis on interfaces, you should consider changing the type of the `bays` property from `List<IBay>` to `IList<IBay>`. This would allow consumers to assign `IBay[]` arrays to it.

Comment: Thanks. This was a question about how I should set up my interfaces to begin with. I was unclear what was the best practice. Your answer gives me exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.